# Writing form with Flask-triangle does not work

Tags: python, flask

I've been trying to create a form with Flask-Triangle for hours now and i can't get it to work. I've been trying to read the documentation but nothing helps.

HTML:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Login {% endblock %}
{% block body %}

    <div class="col-md-4" id="offset"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form name="profile">
            {% for widget in form %}
                <label>{{ widget.label }}</label> {{ widget }}
            {% endfor %}
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>

{% endblock %}
```

Python:

```
    class Profile(Form):
        uname = TextInput('profile.uname', label='Username', required=True)
        password = TextInput('profile.password', label='Password', required=True)
        confirmPassword = TextInput('profile.confirmPassword', label='Confirm Password', required=True)

app = Flask(__name__)
Triangle(app)
widgets = Widgets(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('login.html', form=Profile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug="true")
```

The error i'm getting: "TypeError: 'FormBase' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the class `Profile` to your template. You need to pass an instance of it instead.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('login.html', form=Profile())
```

Comment: Thank you! 
What i did that worked was Profile(Form) and it worked :)